# Angular MatTable doesn't re-render table when data array changes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular material v15.2.1 and created a table with `ng generate @angular/material:table clubsTable`.
The data to be displayed in the table are retrieved asynchronously.

The problem is: When loading the page, the table with the columns is shown correctly, at first zero rows are displayed, in the lower right corner it says '0 of 0'. As soon as the data has been retrieved asynchronously, in the lower right corner it says '1 – 50 of 69'. But the rows are not displayed. Only when I switch to the second page or change the displayed lines per page the rows are displayed.

I call the method `this.table.renderRows()` after the data has been received.
Can someone tell me why the table is not being updated?

clubs-table.component.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- shortname Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="shortname">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Kürzel</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.shortname}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- lastname Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Nachname</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.lastname}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- firstname Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Vorname</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.firstname}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- street Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="street">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Straße</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.street}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- plz Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="plz">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>PLZ</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.plz}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- place Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="place">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ort</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.place}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- phone Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Telefon</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.phone}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- email Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.email}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data?.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100]"
      aria-label="Select page">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

clubs-table.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ClubsTableDataSource } from './clubs-table-datasource';

import { IClub } from 'src/app/models/database.model';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/services/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clubs-table',
  templateUrl: './clubs-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clubs-table.component.css']
})
export class ClubsTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<IClub>;
  dataSource: ClubsTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'shortname', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'street', 'plz', 'place', 'phone', 'email'];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    this.dataSource = new ClubsTableDataSource();
    this.getData();
  }

  async getData() {
    this.httpService.getAllClubs().then((clubs) => {
      this.dataSource.data = clubs.clubs;
      this.table.renderRows();
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

clubs-table-datasource.ts

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

import { IClub } from 'src/app/models/database.model';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/services/http.service';

export class ClubsTableDataSource extends DataSource<IClub> {
  data: IClub[] = new Array<IClub>;
  paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  sort: MatSort | undefined;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<IClub[]> {
    if (this.paginator && this.sort) {
      // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
      // stream for the data-table to consume.
      return merge(observableOf(this.data), this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange)
        .pipe(map(() => {
          return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data ]));
        }));
    } else {
      throw Error('Please set the paginator and sort on the data source before connecting.');
    }
  }

  disconnect(): void {}

  private getPagedData(data: IClub[]): IClub[] {
    if (this.paginator) {
      const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
      return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }

  private getSortedData(data: IClub[]): IClub[] {
    if (!this.sort || !this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort?.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort?.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'shortname': return compare(a.shortname, b.shortname, isAsc);
        case 'lastname': return compare(a.lastname, b.lastname, isAsc);
        case 'firstname': return compare(a.firstname, b.firstname, isAsc);
        case 'street': return compare(a.street, b.street, isAsc);
        case 'plz': return compare(a.plz, b.plz, isAsc);
        case 'place': return compare(a.place, b.place, isAsc);
        case 'phone': return compare(a.phone, b.phone, isAsc);
        case 'email': return compare(a.email, b.email, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean): number {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

I would expect that after the lines `this.dataSource.data = clubs.clubs;` and `this.table.renderRows();` are executed the rows are displayed, so i mean that the table is automatically rerendered.